# What is Bitcoin's "genesis hash"?

Tags: lightning-network, hash, genesis-block, endianness

From Lightning Network [documentation](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/00-introduction.md):

> Used in several of the BOLT documents to denote the genesis hash of a target
>   blockchain. This allows nodes to create and reference channels on
>   several blockchains. Nodes are to ignore any messages that reference a
>   chain_hash that are unknown to them. Unlike bitcoin-cli, the hash is
>   not reversed but is used directly.
>
> For the main chain Bitcoin blockchain, the chain_hash value MUST be
>   (encoded in hex):
>   6fe28c0ab6f1b372c1a6a246ae63f74f931e8365e15a089c68d6190000000000.

However this wiki entry about Bitcoin's [genesis block](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block) has

> GetHash()      =
>   0x000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f

Indeed, inputting the latter value into blockchain.info yields [Block 0](https://blockchain.info/block-index/14849/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f), while the former value cannot be found on blockchain.info.

Why does the value `6fe28c0ab6f1b372c1a6a246ae63f74f931e8365e15a089c68d6190000000000` appear in Lightning Network as "Bitcoin's genesis hash"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're exactly the same number; one is written in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) notation and the other is big endian.  Notice that the bytes (two-hex-digit pairs) are exactly reversed from one to the other.

Block explorers like blockchain.info usually expect big-endian for block hashes.  The proof-of-work requirement means that the *most* significant bits have to be zero, so big endian makes it easier to see this.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same hash but reversed since bitcoin transmits data using little endian format (most significant byte last)

Answer (score 0):

Also of note, the present [testnet genesis](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/block/000000000933ea01ad0ee984209779baaec3ced90fa3f408719526f8d77f4943/):

Big Endian (typical for blockchain explorers):

`000000000933ea01ad0ee984209779baaec3ced90fa3f408719526f8d77f4943`

Little Endian (correct for [block header](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/block-header)):

`43497fd7f826957108f4a30fd9cec3aeba79972084e90ead01ea330900000000`